# How to update a Listview with Pull to update in Xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Good Morning! I'm having a bit of trouble implementing a PullToRefresh in a listview could anyone help me?

Comment: I am sorry, but this is _not_ a great question for StackOverflow. We expect a bit more effort on your part. What have you tried already? Show us some code, where did you fail? Did you get any error messages? Please read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask a good question. Because the question like it is right now can easily be found in any tutorial on this subject on the internet.

Comment: I'm starting now and I do not understand very well how to implement the function more thank you I'll search the network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are plenty of existing resources available if you are willing to perform a quick google search. Here are a few useful ones [Link 1](https://xamarinhelp.com/pull-to-refresh-listview/), [Link 2](http://motzcod.es/post/113280718807/official-pull-to-refresh-in-xamarinforms-140).

The short and long if it is that if you're implementing it through the XAML then you simply do the following:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}" 
      IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True" 
      RefreshCommand="{Binding RefreshCommand}" 
      IsRefreshing="{Binding IsRefreshing}" />
```

'RefreshCommand' relates to a method in your backing class that runs whatever code you want to run when the pull down to refresh is activated.

'IsRefreshing' is a boolean that's bound to a true or false to dictate when the listview should show the activity indicator. This can be started and stopped within your 'RefreshCommand' if you so choose.

This can also be implemented in the C# code behind if you'd rather, there are plenty of guides available for this approach too.

Comment: Thank you @Digitalsa1nt ! It was a great help.